# Bullet physics(ammo.js in asm.js) how to get collision impact force

Tags: javascript, physics, emscripten, bullet, ammo.js

So I managed to get collisions detection working in ammo.js like they do in Physijs. Here's the code which works

```
var i,
    dp = this.dispatcher,
    num = dp.getNumManifolds(),
    manifold, num_contacts, j, pt;

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    manifold = dp.getManifoldByIndexInternal(i);

    num_contacts = manifold.getNumContacts();
    if (num_contacts === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < num_contacts; j++) {
        pt = manifold.getContactPoint(j);

        //console.log('body 1: ', manifold.getBody0());
        //console.log('body 2: ', manifold.getBody1());

        console.log('COLLISION DETECTED!');
        // HERE: how to get impact force details?
        // pt.getAppliedImpulse() is not working
    }
}
```

On some forums I found that this function gives information about impact force:

```
getAppliedImpulse()
```

but there's no such function in ammo.js. I text searched the code and it's not there. Maybe the API is newer or the approach to reading force is completely different?

**Edit:**

Here's my custom-built ammo with getAppliedImpulse() and many essential functions enabled.
https://github.com/DVLP/ammo.js/tree/master/builds

Comment: I don't know ammo.js, but I know Physics; **force** and **impulse** are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a binding description to `ammo.idl`, and rebuild ammo.js.

```
interface btManifoldPoint {
    ...
    [Const] double getAppliedImpulse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the correct answer which I figured out too. Unfortunately I can't build ammo.js on Windows which is a known issue. Also I'm not switching to Mac like other front end/JavaScript devs. Maybe I'll get a spare one just to build ammo lol

Comment: Here's my fork of ammo(built) with this option enabled if anyone has the same need https://github.com/DVLP/ammo.js/tree/master/builds